# Multi-Table Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

**Database Diagram:**

[image: Database Diagram]

I created a database for a statistics program, it works except that I want to get games based on season and team... I'm able to get all the dates that there are games on in that season but they aren't grouped by the team.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: Could you please post your table definition statements, some sample data, desired resultset and the query you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
    SELECT * FROM TEAMS as T
    INNER JOIN SEASONS as S
        ON T.ID = S.TeamId
WHERE S.Season = //Your Season Here
       AND T.Name = //Your Team Name Here
```